# Getting user input by JTextField in Java?

Tags: java

I am trying to get user inputs from a textbox so I can take the user input to calculate the displacement for a ball.

I  tried this

```
double initialvelocity = new JTextBox("enter your initial velocity");
```

so I have a variable with data that I can use. I just cant get it to work and this has been a obstacle to my first proper java project.

Could anyone suggest how I can get a variable to store data using `JTextField` or is there other alternatives?

Comment: Do you mean JTextField maybe in the code sample?

Answer (score 9):

A JTextField should be stored like this:

```
JTextField v0TextField = new JTextField ("initial velocity");
```

And when you want to access the current string in the text box:

```
String strV0TextBox = v0TextField.getText();
```

Then you'll want to parse this into a double:

```
double initialvelocity = Double.parseDouble(strV0TextField);
```

Comment: why the weird variable naming? What about `initialVelocityTextField`, `initialVelocityString` and `initialVelocity`?

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to get input from the user the easiest way is to use a dialog:

```
double value = Double.parseDouble(
           JOptionPane.showInputDialog("please enter value"));
```

Comment: Haha, not really.  BTW please accept an answer if it solved your problem please.

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to use `JTextField` is

```
JTextField box = new JTextField(" Enter Initial Velocity");
String velocity_str = box.getText();
```

Than parse into a double

```
double initialvelocity = Double.parseDouble(velocity_str);
```

Answer (score 2):

See this tutorial for using a jTextField [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html).

You want to instantiate the box like:

```
    JTextField myTextField = new JTextField("enter your initial velocity");

    //Probably should do some kind of validation on the input if you only want numbers
    //get The Text and parse it as a double
    double initVelocity = Double.parseDouble(myTextField.getText());
```

Comment: I get a type mismatch as string and double cannot be added together

Comment: @user1183685 updated to include the string to double conversion.