# Getting errors when using .getText() with Integer.parseInt()

Tags: java

So I'm trying to make a programme that when an integer, i.e 5, is entered into the textarea, one of three buttons is clicked which runs a method with the integer taken from the textarea and puts it into a for loop. I'm not concerned about the methods for now, I'm just trying to get my programme to run.

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {

static JTextField textfield = new JTextField("Enter the size of your shape: ");
static String size = textfield.getText();
static int w = Integer.parseInt(size);
static JTextArea textarea = new JTextArea(6, 37) ;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();// creating instance of JFrame

    JButton bSquare = new JButton("Square");// creating instance of JButton
    JButton bRATriangle = new JButton("Right Angle Triangle");// creating instance of JButton
    JButton bETriangle = new JButton("Equilateral Triangle");// creating instance of JButton

    bSquare.setBounds(50, 100, 100, 40);// x axis, y axis, width, height
    bRATriangle.setBounds(250, 100, 100, 40);// x axis, y axis, width, height
    bETriangle.setBounds(450, 100, 100, 40);// x axis, y axis, width, height
    textfield.setBounds(200, 200, 200, 80);

    bSquare.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            for(int i = 0; i > w; i++) {
                textfield.setText("YEAH BOIIIIIII!");
            }
        }
    });
```

When I do try to run the programme, I get the following errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Enter the size of your shape: "
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at Main.<clinit>(Main.java:8)
```

Any ideas on how to fix it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Enter the size of your shape: " is not a number.

Comment: *What* are you expecting the first 3 variables to do? Clearly a crash is happening. You should add the textfield to a view, add a button or onChange-Listener and only then `try` to parse the text.

Comment: You create the text field with the text "Enter the size of your shape:" and then immediately you get that text back and try and convert it to a number.

Comment: In fairness to OP, this is apparently a [common](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9103226/getting-user-input-by-jtextfield-in-java) way to do this. Just the code needs to happen in a listener.

Comment: You should understand that your program will not bind the value of getText automatically to your variable. You must write code whhich will get the text value in runtime. in your case you should write code inside the actionperformed method.

Comment: It'd probably make more sense if `"Enter the size of your shape:"` was in a `JLabel` beside your textfield. Or a tooltip.

Answer (score 1):

all this are static

```
static JTextField textfield = new JTextField("Enter the size of your shape: ");
static String size = textfield.getText();
static int w = Integer.parseInt(size);
static JTextArea textarea = new JTextArea(6, 37) ;
```

so they are executed after the class is loaded not giving you the chance to give the input...

solution is: dont use static objects and this JTextField textfield should be empty and only used for the number input

Comment: Note to OP: The class being loaded isn't the same thing as being instantiated.

Comment: I still get the same errors despite removing the static objects and leaving textfield blank. @ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ

Answer (score 0):

You parse the `String` to convert it into a `Integer` in the field declaration :

```
static String size = textfield.getText();
int w = Integer.parseInt(size);
```

It makes no sense.
You should add a Listener to the `textfield` field and in this listener performs this conversion with a try/catch of course.
As you are not sure of the input is a `Integer`, you should handle the exception case.

For example :

```
textfield.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     try{
       w = Integer.parseInt(textfield.getText());
     }
      catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
         ... // handle the exception
      } 
  }
 }
```